# Will iOS core image filters be fast enough for live camera effects?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, core-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the Core Image filters in iOS 5.0 fast enough for realtime video processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625888/are-the-core-image-filters-in-ios-5-0-fast-enough-for-realtime-video-processing)

I'm wondering if core image will be fast enough to apply live filter and effects to the camera video?

What would be a good starting point to learn the core image framework for iOS?