# IOS 5: Image Filters

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, core-image

i'm searching about image filters using ios5 sdk but i have two questions:

1. For Mac Os X seems to be a lot of filters that are not available in IOS SDK. Is it possible to implement them or have they already been implemented?
2. Is there an open-source library with filters like Instragram uses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create your own custom CoreImage filters by implementing your own kernel. The kernel will be applied using CoreImage's hardware acceleration, see: [Creating Custom Filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH207-TPXREF101)
2. There are a number of open-source image libraries. We use ImageMagick in some of our iOS apps. A iOS library is even available for [download](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#iOS).

Comment: To clarify (1): The answer is no. If they are not available in the iOS SDK then you will have to implement your own kernel or filter.

Comment: Option 1 is incorrect for iOS. Custom kernels are not available.

Comment: You can't create custom Core Image filters on iOS as of 5.0.

Comment: Uhhh yeah Akaru stated that 5 months ago. ;) Regardless, my answer still helped the person. Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 5):

Core Image on iOS lacks many of the filters that are present on the Mac, such as blurs and other more complex operations. You also cannot write custom filters in Core Image as of iOS 5.1.

My newer [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework lets you write custom filters, and it has many of the ones missing from Core Image on iOS, such as unsharp masking and edge detection. It's also [much faster than Core Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6628208/19679) in most cases. I built this framework specifically to address the current shortcomings of Core Image on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this open source library based on c/c++ , and this is the  [library link](http://gmic.sourceforge.net/gimp.shtml)