# Apply filter to camera input using backgroundFilters for CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone app with camera, and I am trying to apply filter to the video input and show filtered video on the screen.

I thought about applying the filter on the method captureOutput as:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter    filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" 
                                    keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, 
                                    image, @"inputIntensity", 
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                                    nil];
    videoCALayer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:filter];
    [videoCALayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKeyPath:@"filters.CISepiaTone.inputScale"];
}
```

I am trying to set the backgroundFilters array, and then set the first filter for CALayer, but its not working, can anyone suggest how it is done? Thanks.

Comment: Someone has a full working sample of the very same filter [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778117/video-filtering-in-iphone-is-slow

Comment: That post is actually mine as well, yeah it works, but I am using a different technique there. I want to do the filtering using CALayer backgroundFilters method. Thanks.