# iOS, FFmpeg render video with UIimage vs OpenGL

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ffmpeg, sdl

I have an IP camera that streams h264 video over RTSP. On iOS I use FFmpeg to capture the RTSP stream and decode the frames then render with an UIimage and UIimageview.

I have seen examples of of rendering video from FFmpeg, they all seem to use OpenGL ES or the SDL library.

My question is what are the benefits for using OpenGL? since rendering with UIimage is easy and seem to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SDL and OpenGL are portable, cross-platform standards
- These libraries use the GPU for processing data. This is really efficient for graphics processing and enables you - for example - to apply realtime filters to the video.

Apple offers CIImage for processing image data on the GPU. This can be a more cocoa-centric way of providing some of the benefits of openGL and SDL. See [Are the Core Image filters in iOS 5.0 fast enough for realtime video processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625888/are-the-core-image-filters-in-ios-5-0-fast-enough-for-realtime-video-processing) for some useful discussion of this.

If you don't need to apply filters, and don't require cross-platform code, your working method is fine.

Comment: SDL is a complete ui toolkit, its best suited for applications were cross compatibility is of priority and does not need to be integrated into an app that makes extensive use of apple uikit, we do a lot with sdl and have found that it does not behave really nice in conjecture with certain apple components. Apple offers AVFoundation that can be used along with ffmpeg to provide similar capability, open gl as mentioned uses the GPU, but nesting open gl views is painful and mixing open gl views with apple uikit elements tend to affect performance.

Comment: Using UIImage gives you more component flexibility at the cost of some performance, UImageView based players tend to handle adverse bandwidth changes poorly. Its

Comment: Its also possible to render to an off screen frame buffer (FBO) which can render an uiimage were needed. This gives you the flexibility of open gl in terms of scaling with the convenience of using an uiimage, We tend to use all of the above methods in our applications. if you follow standard Model View Controller design principles thats pretty easy.