# How to do real time video editing by applying CIFilters in iOS 5 & iOS 6 maintaining 30 FPS [Frames Per Second]?

Tags: avfoundation, core-image, core-video, cifilter, core-media

I am new to real-time video editing in iPhone.My goal is to achieve highest frame rate during video editing while working on GPU. I want to support iOS 5 & above with available CIFilters.

Kindly guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use Core Image, or can you work with alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625888/are-the-core-image-filters-in-ios-5-0-fast-enough-for-realtime-video-processing/6628208#6628208 ?

Comment: Hello Brad, I already saw your work and Framework which you built. That is great work i appreciate that, and i am expecting you to comment on my question as well. Here i want to use AVFoundation and CIFilters which are available in iOS. I am unable to understand CAEAGLLayer provided by apple and i really wanted to get the WWDC 2012 demo from episode 510-511 if that is possible.