# Key differences between Core Image and GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, core-image

What are the major differences between the Core Image and GPUImage frameworks (besides GPUImage being open source)?  At a glance their interfaces seem pretty similar... Applying a series of filters to an input to create an output.  I see a few small differences, such as the  easy to use LookupFilter that GPUImage has.  I am trying to figure out why someone would choose one over the other for a photo filtering application.

Comment: Have you read any of the info on GPUImage's readme file? This is all outlined there.

Comment: Thanks.. Is it safe to assume exporting filtered video is faster than Core Image as well?

Comment: GPUImage is not necessarily faster than Core Image, and vice versa. Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't. You should see which framework fits your needs best.

Comment: @lxt can you expand on that?  I'm mostly interested in performance.

Comment: Ivan, if the image is on the GPU you can expect some very good speed gains on per-pixel image processing since the GPU is designed exactly for that. Downfalls can be on creating the GPUImage since those image data will probably have to be moved(copied) in memory and same for getting the result image back to the CPU memory. Other then that you can expect some memory increase (but not necessary). Generally if you are doing some heavy image processing on reasonably large images you will have a performance gain using the GPU.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As the author of GPUImage, you may want to take what I say with a grain of salt. I should first say that I have a tremendous amount of respect for the Core Image team and how they continue to update the framework. I was a heavy Core Image user before I wrote GPUImage, and I patterned many of its design elements based on how Core Image worked on the Mac.

Both frameworks are constantly evolving, so a comparison made today might not be true in a few months. I can point to current capabilities and benchmarks, but there's no guarantee that won't flip when either of us update things.

My philosophy with GPUImage was to create a lightweight wrapper around OpenGL (ES) quads rendered with shaders, and to do so with as simple an interface as possible. As I stated earlier, I pulled in aspects of Core Image that I really liked, but I also changed portions of their interface that had tripped me up in the past. I also extended things a bit, in that Core Image only deals with image processing, while I hook in movie playback, camera input, video recording, and image capture.

When I originally was kicking around the idea for this, Core Image had not yet come to iOS. By the time I released it, Core Image had just been added to iOS. However, the number of filters supported on iOS at that time [was fairly limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters) (no blurs, for example), and Core Image on iOS did not allow you to create custom kernels as it did on the Mac.

GPUImage provided the means to do custom GPU-accelerated operations on images and video on iOS, where Core Image did not. Most people who started using it did so for that reason, because they had some effect that they could not do with stock Core Image filters.

Initially, GPUImage also [had significant performance advantages for many common operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6628208/19679). However, the Core Image team has made significant improvements in processing speed with each iOS version and things are very close right now. For some operations, GPUImage is faster, and for others, Core Image is faster. They look to employ some [pretty clever optimizations for things like blurs](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu), which I've started to replicate in things like my GPUImageiOSBlurFilter. They also combine multi-stage operations intelligently, where I treat filter steps as discrete and separate items. In some cases on iOS, this gives me an advantage, and I've tried to reduce the memory consequences of this recently, but they handle many types of filter chains better than I do.

iOS 8 introduces the custom kernel support in Core Image on iOS that it has always had on the Mac. This makes it possible to write your own custom filters and other operations in Core Image on iOS, so that will no longer be as much of an advantage for GPUImage. Of course, anyone wanting to target an older iOS version will still be limited by what Core Image can do there, where GPUImage can target back to iOS 4.0.

Core Image also has some neat capabilities in terms of being able to do filtering while an iOS application is in the background (CPU-based at first, but iOS 8 adds GPU-side support for this now), where GPUImage's reliance on OpenGL ES prevents it from running when an application is in the background. There might be ways around this limitation in iOS 8, but I haven't worked through all the documentation yet.

My interests with GPUImage are in the field of machine vision. The image filters are a fun distraction, but I want to use this framework to explore what's possible with GPU-accelerated image analysis. I'm working on arbitrary object recognition and tracking operations, and that's the direction I'll continually evolve the framework toward. However, you have [the code](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to the framework, so you don't have to rely on me.

Comment: Hi Sir, is there any updates for this answer now at 2022.04?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but I think it's worth noting that GPUImage also has some features that are not present in Core Image: notably hough transform and several edge detection filters.

Core Image seems all about applying filters and effects — and it's good to see GPUImage explores more on image/video analysis, kind of becoming more like openCV, but in a more efficient way.